# sql query giving inconsistent results

Tags: mysql, sql, date, timestamp

I have an sql database with an orders table with primary key as order_no(int) and order_dispatch_date (timestamp).
I have 46 rows that have the date(order_dispatch_date) as '2017-12-09', but when I do the following query, it displays only 45 rows:

```
select * from orders where date(order_dispatch_date)=('2017-12-09')
```

So i further investigated and found out that an order_no 1029547 was not getting displayed in the results and thats where my problem was.
I also executed this query which gives me the same result, 45 rows except the row with order_no 1029547

```
 SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE date(order_dispatch_date)=(SELECT date(order_dispatch_date) from orders WHERE order_no=1029547)
```

Why is the row with order_no 1029547 not getting displayed in both the results, while it gets displayed in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE date(order_dispatch_date)=date('2017-12-09') and order_no=1029547
```

Please help me figure out the problem.

Comment: The date value for the special order number probably also has a time portion

Comment: can you share the structure of the table?

Comment: What is the result for _SELECT date(order_dispatch_date) from orders WHERE order_no=1029547_ ?

Comment: Result for select date(order_dispatch_date) from orders where order_no=1029547 is 2017-12-09

Answer (score 0):

I copied the timestamp from an order which was getting displayed in the 45 rows in the order_dispatch_date of order_no 1029547, i still get 45 rows when i execute the select * from orders where date(order_dispatch_date)=‘2017-12-09’

Comment: put this answer in comment